# How do I display a field's hidden characters in the result of a query in H2?

Tags: database, h2

I have a varchar field in an h2 database that I'd like to be able to see each character of (including special characters like new line and carriage return).

Basically, I need to know the h2 equivalent of [Oracle's dump()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092703/how-do-i-display-a-fields-hidden-characters-in-the-result-of-a-query-in-oracle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rawtohex()](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#rawtohex) works, but [stringencode()](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#stringencode) is probably simpler, as it returns the Java encoded string:

```
select rawtohex('test' || char(13) || char(444));
> 0074006500730074000d01bc

select stringencode('test' || char(13) || char(444));
> test\r\u01bc
```

Answer (score 1):

I should've kept looking. Found it in the [h2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/h2.pdf): rawtohex().